# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) when using rmongodbHelper

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I'm working with rmongodb and rmongodbHelper packages and i've built this function.

```
CUPS_CP_TAR36 <- function(codi,cant){
  cups <- vector()
  query <- json_to_bson('{"clLst.U_COD_POSTAL": codi, "clLst.TARIFA_ATR": {"$in": "3.0A","3.1A","6.1"]}}')
  output <- json_to_bson('{"id":1}')
  cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, sips, query, fields=output, limit=cant)
  k = 0
  while(mongo.cursor.next(cursor)){
    k = k + 1
    cups[k] <- mongo.bson.value(mongo.cursor.value(cursor), "_id") 
  }
    return(cups)  
}
```

but when I try to use it:

```
example <- CUPS_CP_TAR36(codi="08036", cant=10)
```

I get the following error and really dont know why, i'm not used to write my own functions:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'codi' not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try latest rmongodb version from [github](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb). bson from json works out of the box. Moreover `mongo.bson.to.list` works fine for every case, so you dont't need to construct bson from json. I have plans to push new version of the package to CRAN next week.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mongosoup/rmongodb")
```

Comment: Does also mongo.bson.from.JSON() now work for all cases (arrays, subdocuments, ...)?

Comment: yes!!! Now rmongodb converts json arrays into **unnamed** lists. Moreover today I will push fix( or enhancement:-)) for converting simple arrays (```integer, numeric, logical, POSIX```) into R arrays instead of lists. Please test it.

Comment: cool! so the fix will also allow to convert the following JSON to a valid BSON? {"arr":["string",3.14,[1,"2",[3],{"four":4}],{"mol":42}]}? I would put an announcement for this on the GitHub-repo and my website

Comment: after creating bson and inserting it in mongo, I have this object in mongo: ```{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543e6162563d081250d05777"),
    "arr" : [ 
        "string", 
        3.14, 
        [ 
            1, 
            "2", 
            [ 
                3
            ], 
            {
                "four" : 4
            }
        ], 
        {
            "mol" : 42
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: awesome! thanks for taking the time to fix this issue!

Comment: If you have any troubles, feel free to add issue on github issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

```
query <- json_to_bson('{"clLst.U_COD_POSTAL": codi, ...}')
```

`json_to_bson()` expects a JSON string. The string you provide is not valid JSON, just as `{"key":val}` is not valid - while `{"key":"val"}` or `{"key":3.14}` are valid.

Of course `codi` isn't even intended by you to be a string in your case but to be a variable. But as you write the code there is no way for R to know about that.

So you might write:

```
query <- json_to_bson(sprintf('{"clLst.U_COD_POSTAL": "%s", ...}',codi))
```

The equivalent expression with your value of codi is then:

```
query <- json_to_bson('{"clLst.U_COD_POSTAL": "08036", ...}')
```

The reason why there is an error message involving `eval()` is b/c I wrote the interpretation of the JSON very, very simple - mind this "package" is merely a workaround and hopefully superfluous very soon.

The JSON is turned into a `list()`-expression using string-substitution and then `eval()`ed.

[rmongodbHelper / R / json_to_list.R](https://github.com/joyofdata/rmongodbHelper/blob/master/R/json_to_list.R):

```
json_to_list <- function(json) {
  json <- gsub("\n","",json)
  json <- gsub("\\{\\}","list()",json)
  [...]
  json <- gsub("\\$","_$",json)

  return(eval(parse(text = json)))
}
```

---

Further details: [MongoDB – State of the R](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/mongodb-state-of-the-r-rmongodb/)